# Is there a way to select different columns based on a condition?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

**EDIT to remove ambiguity: view as in MVC and not a database view.**

Hello,

I'm facing a design decision each time I develop database driven applications. Lets say I have a table X and I want to fetch different columns based on the view. A view might require a column, another view my require all columns.

What I'm currently doing is having a single stored procedure that returns all columns `select * from X` and I bind the columns depending on the view. I don't believe this is the correct approach as I'm selecting unnecessary columns and the database is huge and the traffic is increasing.

What's the best way to approach this kind of design? Should I keep the 1 SP way or having a stored procedure for each view (each SP returns different columns). Is there any design pattern that might be useful here? I thought about specifying the columns for the SP but it will make maintenance a nightmare since I have to keep track of the columns argument for each view.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that all of your uses of "view" in your question relate to Views in an MVC (or MVP) application, and not to SQL Views?

Comment: That's correct, sorry for the ambiguous use of the word view.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sold on using stored procedures for your data access, then I'd prefer to use one stored proc per view. You could even introduce a convention such that the procedure name and the view name have some form of 1-1 correspondence.

This would mean that you could easily determine which stored proc is used by each view. It also means that you can apply suitable (different) filters in each procedure, pass different parameters, etc.

I assume you're doing direct database access rather than using some form of ORM or DAL. Most of these systems, if they have strong support for stored procedures, are built around the premise that the stored proc will always return result sets with the same "shape" (i.e. the same columns).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter to the SP to identify the list of columns to retrieve and dynamically execute the statement and return.

You could do it two different ways:

- Pass the list of columns as a string to the stored procedure. It is unsafe and difficult to track what is accessed
- Pass an id representing the list of columns to retrieve. This id could be used to look up a configuration table storing the most relevant column sets (not all possible subsets of course). It is more secure and more manageable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The look up configuration table sounds interesting. I will try to explore it myself, however, have you done something like that before? If so, could you give an example? thanks.

Comment: I did but I don't know which languages and database you are using, so it might not be relevant here :)

Comment: May I ask why does it matter? Isn't this issue (I consider it an issue) language/db agnostic?

Comment: You may, I am not familiar with all DBMS so I am not sure if the dynamic statement execution is supported. The client app was written in .NET, columns set ids were mapped as an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a parameter to the stored procedure, you can use the CASE statement to return different values (from different columns). The actual column name would be fixed, though.

Pseudocode:

```
procedure get_stuff (@p_what varchar)
as
begin

  select case @p_what
      when 'NAME' then t.name
      when 'DESCR' then t.description
      else null
    end as the_column
  from my_table t

end
```

Comment: I don't know why I haven't thought about case. I'm over thinking it beyond over thinking! I will write a fast prototype to see how things will progress.

Comment: @Ali: Consider marking this as the accepted solution if it solves your problem, and/or upvoting the answer.